# What's the difference in GCC between -std=gnu++0x and -std=c++0x and which one should be used?

Tags: android, c++, gcc, c++11, compiler-options

I'm having troubles with `<stdint.h>` when using `-std=c++0x` in GCC 4.4.3 (for Android):

```
// using -std=c++0x
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t value;  // error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type
```

But using `-std=gnu++0x` works:

```
// using -std=gnu++0x
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t value;  // OK
```

Is `<stdint.h>` incompatible with C++0x?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So far as I can tell, I think this could be argued an implementation bug (or actually, since C++0x isn't published, not a bug *per se* but an incomplete implementation of the current state of the upcoming standard).

Here's why, referring to n3225 for the expected behavior of `-std=c++0x`:

D.7 says

> Every C header, each of which has a
>   name of the form name.h, behaves as if
>   each name placed in the standard
>   library namespace by the corresponding
>   cname header is placed within the
>   global namespace scope

OK, so far so easy. What does `<cstdint>` place in the standard library namespace?

18.4.1:

```
typedef unsigned integer type uint64_t; // optional
```

How optional? 18.4.1/2:

> The header deﬁnes all functions,
>   types, and macros the same as 7.18 in
>   the C standard

Drat. What does the C standard say? Taking out n1256, 7.18.1.1/3:

> These types are optional. However,
>   if an implementation provides integer
>   types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64
>   bits, no padding bits, and (for the
>   signed types) that have a
>   two's complement representation, it
>   shall deﬁne the corresponding typedef
>   names

But hang on, surely on Android with `-std=c++0x` GCC *does* provide a 64 bit unsigned type with no padding bits: `unsigned long long`. So `<cstdint>` is required to provide `std::uint64_t` and hence `stdint.h` is required to provide `uint64_t` in the global namespace.

Go on, someone tell me why I'm wrong :-) One possibility is that C++0x refers to "ISO/IEC 9899:1999 Programming languages — C" without specifying a version. Can it really be that (a) 7.18.1.1/3 was added in one of the TCs, and also (b) C++0x intends to reference the original standard as of 1999, not the amendments since then? I doubt either of these is the case, but I don't have the original C99 on hand to check (a) and I'm not even sure how to check (b).

Edit: oh, as for which one should be used `-std=c++0x` isn't really a strict standards-compliant mode yet, since there isn't a strict standard yet. And even if there was a standard, gcc 4.4.3 certainly isn't a finished implementation of it. So I see no great need to use it if `-std=gnu++0x` is actually *more complete*, at least in this respect for your combination of gcc version and platform.

However, `gnu++0x` will enable other GNU extensions, that you might not want your code to use. If you're aiming to write portable C++0x, then eventually you'd want to switch to `-std=c++0x`. But I don't think GCC 4.4 or any other C++0x implementation-in-progress is complete enough yet for it to be practical to write code from the (draft) standard, such that you could say with a straight face "I'm programming C++0x, and it's only 2011!". So I'd say, use whichever one works, and understand that whichever one you use now, you'll probably be switching to `-std=c++11` eventually anyway.

Comment: Same problem with NDK 8b which uses GCC 4.6.