# Compiling ICU for Android - 'uint64_t' does not name a type

Tags: android, android-ndk, icu

While attempting to cross-compile ICU using android-ndk-r7 in Linux, the following error occurs after configuration when I run 'make'

```
__/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:124: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type
```

This is triggered by the #include <sys/types.h> in icu/source/common/unicode/ptypes.h:25. It appears to be a non-icu issue in android-ndk-n7. In sys/types.h we see

```
#ifdef __BSD_VISIBLE
typedef unsigned char   u_char;
typedef unsigned short  u_short;
typedef unsigned int    u_int;
typedef unsigned long   u_long;

typedef uint32_t       u_int32_t;
typedef uint16_t       u_int16_t;
typedef uint8_t        u_int8_t;
typedef uint64_t       u_int64_t;
#endif
```

The culprint here is uint64_t, which is defined in #include <stdint.h> at the top of the sys/types.h. Here we see

```
#if !defined __STRICT_ANSI__ || __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#  define __STDC_INT64__
#endif

...

#if defined(__STDC_INT64__)
typedef __int64_t     int64_t;
typedef __uint64_t    uint64_t;
#endif
```

If **STRICT_ANSI** or **STDC_VERSION** and therefore **STDC_INT64** are never definied, including sys/types.h will throw an error since uint64_t is never defined. Any code that later calls either int64_t (happens in icu code) and uint64_t will also throw the same error. My temporary fix for this is to define **STDC_INT64** at the top of icu's ptypes.h right before #include <sys/types.h>. Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main issue is that uint64_t isn't a defined type in C versions prior to C99.
The best way to have it defined is to tell gcc which standard you'd like to use.

For c++, that's passing the `-std=gnu++0x` flag. For C, that's passing `-std=c99`

I.e. add a line something like

```
APP_CPPFLAGS= -std=gnu++0x
```

to your Application.mk file.

Alternatively, you can just hack it via your #define; I just wouldn't distribute code with such a hack as it's fragile.

Comment: this is the right answer - but it has to be changed in the configuration file

Comment: I found a strange thing: I have `-std=c++11` defined in my *makefile*, but it anyway needed the `-std=gnu++0x` option. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

-D__STDC_INT64__ allows uint64_t and int64_t to be defined in Android's stdint.h.

However, this is not the ideal fix. The error has to do with Android, stdint and -std=c++0x. See [What's the difference in GCC between -std=gnu++0x and -std=c++0x and which one should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135734/whats-the-difference-in-gcc-between-std-gnu0x-and-std-c0x-and-which-one-s) for further information. If you follow the train of thought, an alternate (better??) fix is to modify the icu configuration script so that it calls for gnu++0x instead of c++0x. That's probably the right thing to do.

```
*** 7238,7244 ****
          OLD_CFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
          OLD_CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS}"
          CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -std=gnu99 -D_GCC_"
!         CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS} -std=c++0x"
          cat confdefs.h - <<_ACEOF >conftest.$ac_ext
  /* end confdefs.h.  */

--- 7241,7247 ----
          OLD_CFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
          OLD_CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS}"
          CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -std=gnu99 -D_GCC_"
!         CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS} -std=gnu++0x"
          cat confdefs.h - <<_ACEOF >conftest.$ac_ext
  /* end confdefs.h.  */

***************
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this situation by adding in to icudefs.mk into CPPFLGAS an option -D__STDC_INT64__

Answer (score 0):

Can you set `-DU_HAVE_UINT64_T=0` ?

Comment: I removed my __STDC_INT64__ hack and tried -DU_HAVE_UINT4_T=0. No love, same error 'uint64_t' does not name a type. The first error is really a bug in Android. If __STDC_INT64__ is not called, it shouldn't make the uint64_t definition in sys/types.h

Comment: I'll fix sys/types.h though and try again.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help. In cstring.h, ICU calls for int64_t (some conversion routines), using -DU_HAVE_UINT4_T=0 doesn't help in this. /__/source/common/cstring.h:109: error: 'int64_t' has not been declared

Comment: But I'll try DU_HAVE_INT64T=0

Comment: Nope - error: 'int64_t' has not been declared even with -DU_HAVE_INT64_T=0

Comment: T_CString_int64ToString(char *buffer, int64_t n, uint32_t radix);
does not check for U_HAVE_INT64_T, and there are a number of other places that call int64_t in ICU.

Comment: @tofutim ptypes.h has:   "#if ! U_HAVE_INT64_T  .. typedef signed long long int64_t" and same for UINT64_t   if !U_HAVE_INTTYPES_H  ... hmm, perhaps inttypes is there but it is broken

Comment: There is inttypes.h in the Android NDK. Should I be writing -DU_HAVE_INTTYPES_H? Where is U_HAVE_INTTYPES_H defined?

Comment: configure detects whether inttypes.h is used. It assumes that if inttypes.h is there, that it contains int64_t.

Comment: It does claim to have found inttypes - configure:6276: checking for inttypes.h
configure:6276: result: yes

Comment: I tried -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 - but this did not help. common/cstring.h:109: error: 'int64_t' has not been declared

Comment: I thought that the problem might be that HAVE_INTTYPES_H = 1 but U_HAVE_INTTYPES_H is not defined. But in config.log I see U_HAVE_INTTYPES_H='1'

Comment: STDC_INT64  may be the right answer then. May be something ICU should define.

Comment: It may be that the problem is related to this: 
putil.cpp:#if (U_PF_MINGW <= U_PLATFORM && U_PLATFORM <= U_PF_CYGWIN) && defined(__STRICT_ANSI__)
putil.cpp:#undef __STRICT_ANSI__
umutex.h:#if defined(__STRICT_ANSI__)

Comment: It seems that the fix is to define __STDC_INT64__

Answer (score 0):

Update to NDK 8e it supports more things from C++11

Also your Application.mk should contains some flags look at my file

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -std=c++11 -DDEBUG=1
APP_USE_CPP0X := true
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.7
```