# Android Cmake: 'uint64_t' does not name a type

Tags: android, c++, boost

I am trying use android cmake to compile a 3rd party library "liblas" with android standalone toolchain. The cpu architecture is arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3. So, the build file has been successfully generated.But when I do `make` the library. it gives me this error
 `/home/user/Android/toolchain443/sysroot/usr/include/sys/types.h:124: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type` .
Therefore, all the included boost library report similar errors.

```
/home/user/Android/toolchain443/user/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:126: error: '::int64_t' has not been declared
```

```
/home/li/Android/toolchain443/user/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:127: error: '::int_least64_t' has not been declared
```

```
/home/li/Android/toolchain443/user/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:128: error: '::int_fast64_t' has not been declared
```

what's going on here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247151/compiling-icu-for-android-uint64-t-does-not-name-a-type Possible duplicate?

Comment: @Digital_Reality: the question is same, but the solution I am expecting is different. I am using android cmake. there is no application.mk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something this in your cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu++0x -D__STDC_INT64__")
```

Comment: Try also with CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS variable. This variable for c++ code.